# Bind unique click event to each item in repeater (ajax/jquery)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

ok so I have this repeater:

```
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep"  >
        <ItemTemplate> 
        <tr>
        <td>           
        <div id="resultDiv">
        click me
        </div>                      
        </td>
        </tr>            
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

and i have this jquery ajax call:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#resultDiv").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Page.aspx/GetDate",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                        $("#resultDiv").text(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

the problem is that this only works for the first div inside the repeater. If i click any other divs, the click event isn't being fired. 
I know this is because they all have the same id, being "resultDiv".

I am now looking for a way of giving them unique ID's, which is something I can do like this: (inside the repeater itemtemplate)

```
 <td>          
<div id="resultDiv_<%#Eval("divId") %>">
 click me
 </div>
```

This gives all the divs inside the repeater a unique ID, but this way the ajax click event doesnt fire anymore because

```
 $("#resultDiv").click(function () {
```

`resultDiv` is now something like `resultDiv_1` or `resultDiv_2`.

so im looking for something to bind a click event to each div inside the repeater. I tried doing it like this in the ajax call:

```
$("#<%#Eval("divId") %>").click(function ()
```

but this doesn't work and gives me all kinds of errors.

Is there any way i can do this ? Please not that I do not want to use updatepanels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a live event handler, you should use `on` :

```
$("body").on('click', '#resultDiv', function(e) { });
```

If you want to handle all #resultDiv the same way (by using `resultDiv_1` or `resultDiv_2`) you could use :

```
$("body").on('click', 'div[id^=resultDiv]', function(e) { });
```

You might use classes instead of ID's because they aren't unique, you could easily play with them with `addClass` or `removeClass` !

In your case, I would add the same class to each div, and pass a parameter into some data-attr (if you need to have each click to call a different task) :

```
<div id="resultDiv" class="result" data-some-var="some-param">
    click me
</div>
```

And than on your event :

```
$("body").on('click', '.result', function(e) {
    var param = $(this).attr('data-some-var');
    //send or do something different according to the param
});
```

Comment: It's a way passing some datas from the DOM to javascript if you need one, see this [interesting html5 doctor blog](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) :). Do you want to send the **same** ajax request on each resultDiv ?

Comment: kk thanks alot dude, i finally got this to work. about time, I was about to eat my keyboard out of sheer frustration. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(".parent-container-class").on('change', '.my-text-field', function(e) {
      console.log($(this).val());
      /// Do something
 });
```